# Support swipe to dismiss for UIViewControllerRepresentable presented in sheet

Tags: ios, swiftui

It seems if you use `UIViewControllerRepresentable` to implement a view controller in your SwiftUI app, when you present it via `sheet` you cannot swipe to dismiss it. Is there something you need to do to support swipe to dismiss?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var showingPicker = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .onAppear {
                showingPicker = true
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingPicker, content: {
                PHPicker() //cannot swipe to dismiss
                //Text("Test") //can swipe to dismiss
            })
    }
}

struct PHPicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<PHPicker>) -> PHPickerViewController {
        let config = PHPickerConfiguration()
        return PHPickerViewController(configuration: config)
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: PHPickerViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<PHPicker>) { }
}
```

Comment: By default representable consumes all space (in this case entire sheet area) and `PHPickerViewController.view`, looks, has own handling for gestures. So workarounds are possible but might depend on your project goal.

Comment: Is there a view controller you know that works, doesn't have its own gesture handling? I get the same result with `SFSafariViewController` and `MFMailComposeViewController` so I thought it was all view controllers. @Asperi

Comment: `UINavigationController` allows drag to dismiss, so one of possible workaround is to embed your controller into navigation controller - it will be possible to dismiss dragging by navigation bar.

Comment: Interesting! Ok so PHPicker, SFSafari, and MFMailCompose all have nav controllers already. Any other ideas to be able to swipe to dismiss em?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS 17 allows swipe to dismiss for view controllers presented in sheets. You don’t need to do anything to enable this behavior. I tested with SFSafariViewController and MFMailComposeViewController.

Comment: Doesn't work with `UIActivityViewController`

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution is to add something like *handle* to drag (no styling - simplified for demo),

[image: demo]

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showingPicker, content: {
        VStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(Color.gray)
                .frame(width: 60, height: 8)
                .padding(.top, 8)
            PHPicker()
        }
})
```

**Alternate:** the solution is to make presentation by UIKit completely and just pass activation binding inside representable.

Here is a demo of possible approach. Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

[image: demo2]

```
struct PHPickerContentView: View {
    @State var showingPicker = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Picker") {
           showingPicker = true
        }
        .background(PHPicker(isPresented: $showingPicker))    // << here !!
    }
}

struct PHPicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        UIViewController()   // << picker presenter
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {
        // react on binding & show if not shown
        if isPresented && uiViewController.presentedViewController == nil {
            let config = PHPickerConfiguration()
            let picker = PHPickerViewController(configuration: config)
            picker.delegate = context.coordinator

            uiViewController.present(picker, animated: true)
            picker.presentationController?.delegate = context.coordinator
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, PHPickerViewControllerDelegate, UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate {
        let owner: PHPicker
        init(_ owner: PHPicker) {
            self.owner = owner
        }

        func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {

            // picked image handling code here
        
            picker.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true)
            owner.isPresented = false    // << reset on action !!
        }
        
        func presentationControllerDidDismiss(_ presentationController: UIPresentationController) {
            owner.isPresented = false    // << reset on swipe !!
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the simplicity of the solution. The hit only applies to handle itself is something that I find a bit hard to use though.

Comment: @TimBodeit, see also alternate solution.